# Asp.net Core template with Angular 2 giving an error when trying to run

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

Well I am trying to run a visual studio template from
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/31a3eab5-e62b-4030-9226-b5e4c9e1ffb5

As seen on
Steve Anderson's blog
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

An exception of type `System.AggregateException` occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

In Startup.cs this comes up highlighted.

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {

HotModuleReplacement = true

})
```

;

I have run a solution

FIX:
Just run webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js from a command line at the root of the project where the webpack.config.js file is located. NOTE: you must have installed webpack. Once I followed your section on adding third-party libraries, everything clicked.
Thanks for the template!

But this did not work for me.
Banging my head against the wall for this for a while now.

Comment: What are inner exceptions in AggregateException?

Comment: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'publicPath' of undefined
    at createWebpackDevServer (C:\Users\Bilal\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:9:43)
    at module.exports.createWebpackDevServer (C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp85CD.tmp:19:49)
    at C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8726.tmp:113:19
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8726.tmp:132:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)...
....